# Getting list of Inherited types doesn't work for all types

Tags: c#, reflection, inherited

I wrote a small method to list the inherited types but it doesn't works with a `TreeNode` for example:

Assume this classes:

```
class B { }
class A : B { }
class C :TreeNode { }
```

And then:

```
GetInheritedTypes(typeof(A)); //typeof(B)
GetInheritedTypes(typeof(C)); // 0 items
```

The method to list them:

```
List<Type> GetInheritedTypes(Type baseType) 
{ 
    return Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType)
                   .GetTypes()
                   .Where(type => type != baseType && type.IsAssignableFrom(baseType))
                   .ToList(); 
}
```

Why is `GetInheritedTypes(typeof(C))` returning 0 items instead of `Typeof(TreeNode)`?

Comment: Are `C` and `TreeNode` declared in the same assembly?

Comment: Why are you not just using `type.BaseType`? That will get you a type's base type without enumerating every type in an assembly.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: No, they're not, unless Jack here is working on adding a type C to System.Windows.Forms.DLL.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But you can compute that by continually pulling the base type of the base type until you hit `null`.  Far quicker than iterating all types in the assembly (and does in fact work for types outside of the assembly)

Comment: Of course that is not the only way that this query is wrong. Jack believes that assignability and inheritance are the same thing but they are only tangentially related to each other.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Im not sure this does either, it does not recursively call `GetInheritedTypes`

Comment: @EricLippert Good point. Or maybe he has his own `TreeNode` class declared? :)

Comment: @EricLippert: Oh, is this actually asking about [`System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (or maybe about [`System.Web.Ui.WebControls.TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), or a custom class named `TreeNode`?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Good point. But regardless, plainly this code is all messed up.

Comment: @Jamiec `IsAssignableFrom` will return true for a parent of a parent.  it also will return true for types for which there is a valid implicit conversion that isn't related to the inheritance hierarchy (i.e. interfaces implemented).

Comment: Yep, I just tested that. My bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is GetInheritedTypes(typeof(C)) returning 0 items instead of Typeof(TreeNode)?

Because `TreeNode` is not in the same assembly as `C`. Your query is "from all the types in the same assembly as C, give me the ones that C is assignable to".

I suspect however that your actual problem is:

> How do I list all the base types of a given type?

You do *not* do a search over all types in an assembly and check to see which ones are assignable. That's like trying to figure out who your mom is by asking every person in your city "are you Jack's mom?" instead of asking Jack "who's your mom?".

Something like this would be much better:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypes(this Type type)
{
    if (type == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    Type baseType = type;
    while(true)
    {
        baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        if (baseType == null) 
            break;
        yield return baseType;
    }
}
```

A commenter asks

> what if you want to get all the implemented interfaces?

Call `GetInterfaces()` on the type object.

(An earlier version of this post suggested getting the transitive closure of the interfaces; I had forgotten that `GetInterfaces` already does that.)

> How else was my original code broken?

Well, suppose for example you have a type

```
class D<T> {}
```

and a class

```
class E : D<int> {}
```

Now you ask "given `E`, list all the types `X` in the assembly such that a value of type `E` may be assigned to a variable of type `X`".  Well, `D<T>` is in the assembly; is `D<T>` such a type?  No. An `E` is assignable to a variable of type `D<int>`, not a variable of type `D<T>`.

The "assignable" relation and the "inherits from" relation have quite a bit of overlap, but they are not at all the *same* relation, so don't pretend that they are.

Comment: What if type implements multiple interfaces?

Comment: Awesome example. I'm assuming you could then get all the implemented types (excluding the assignable generic types, base types + interfaces) by doing something like `relation = t => t.GetInterfaces().Concat(t.BaseType == null ? Enumerable.Empty<Type>() : new[] { t.BaseType });` correct?

Comment: @moarboilerplate: I removed my awesome example because I realized that it was unnecessary. (I was thinking of the Roslyn implementation of the "all interfaces" relation, not the Reflection implementation.)  But yes, you could get the "transitive closure of all base types and interfaces" as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You are only enumerating classes within the same assembly as `C`, and presumably `TreeNode` resides in a different assembly.